# How can I sort two string arrays of names and put them back together, maintaining sorting integrity?

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

I am taking a text files with names on each line, and trying to sort them based on the length of last name (first priority), then length of first name (second priority). The result should be last name first and look like this, characters represented by x:

xx xx,
xx xxx,
xx xxxx,
xxx xx,
xxx xxx,
xxxx xxx,
etc.

My thought process is to split the string by the white space and sort individually. I've tried to use lists and maps with no luck. I am currently using an array method to try and maintain the integrity of the separated strings. I can sort both arrays by string length, but I cannot figure out how to combine them again without messing up the ordering.

```
val fnbuild = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
val lnbuild = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
val fullbuild = new ArrayBuffer[String]()

for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines){
  val split = line.split(" ")
  fullbuild += line
  //array of full names, first name first
  fnbuild += split(0)
  //array of first names
  lnbuild += split(1)
  //array of last names
}
val fnarray = fnbuild.toArray.sortWith(_.length < _.length)
val lnarray = lnbuild.toArray.sortWith(_.length < _.length)
val refarray = fullbuild.toArray
```

Here I have the arrays all built, but I have no idea how to get the result I desire. Is there an easier way to do this? What steps should I take, if not?

Comment: You say you want to sort "based on the length of the last name AND the length of the first name", which is a little vague but seems to mean sort primarily by length of last name, use length of first name as tie-breaker. If that (or something like it) is the case, how does  xx xxxx come before xxx xx as in your result example?

Comment: How do you deal with names like "David Allan Coe" (last name: Coe) and "Eddie Van Halen" (last name: Van Halen)?

Comment: That's the kicker, it needs to be a list basically completely sorted by the last names, where then in each length of last name, the first names are sorted by length. The first names are only sorted by length for their respective length of last name.

Comment: The list of names is only first and last name.

Comment: @Daniel Sphar, requirement described in your comment seems to be different from that of your question: `sort them based on the length of the last name AND the length of the first name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're description is vague and doesn't match the example results you provide, but I wonder if something like this is what you're after.

```
io.Source.fromFile(filename)
         .getLines
         .toArray
         .sortBy{ line =>
           val Array(fn,ln) = line.split(" ")
           (ln.length, fn.length)
         }
```

Warning: This will only work if the name is 2 strings. It won't handle last names like "van Gogh".

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that maps "fname lname" into a `Tuple` of `(lname.length, lname, fname.length, fname)` followed by a `sorted`, as shown below:

```
// /path/to/file:
// John Doe
// Rachel Johnson
// Mike Dunn
// Jenn Smith
// David Smith

import scala.io.Source

val sortedNames = Source.fromFile("/path/to/file").getLines.
  map{ line =>
    val a = line.split("\\s+")
    (a(1).length, a(1), a(0).length, a(0))
  }.toVector.
  sorted.
  map(t => t._2 + " " + t._4)
// sortedNames: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] =
//    Vector(Doe John, Dunn Mike, Smith Jenn, Smith David, Johnson Rachel)
```

Note that sorting will be performed in the **exact order** of the elements in the Tuple (i.e. `lname's length, lname, fname's length, fname`). 
 Feel free to rearrange the order as you see fit.

Comment: @Daniel Sphar, please see expanded answer.

Comment: I see. My apologies for the confusion. I'm still not quite sure how to describe it, but i updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing two sorts, you need to do a single sort with a function that implements the ordering that you want. It might look like this:

```
def nameOrder(a: String, b: String) = {
  val s1 = a.split("\\s+")
  val s2 = b.split("\\s+")

  if (s1.tail.length == s2.tail.length) {
    s1.head.length < s2.head.length
  } else {
    s1.tail.length < s2.tail.length
  }
}

val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines

lines.sortWith(nameOrder)
```

This is a simple version to make the logic clear. If efficiency is an issue you might want to split the names into tuples, sort the tuples, and then put them together again. You should also compute the lengths once and then compare them.

Comment: This seemed to work for most of them, as it arranged every last name in order. However, there were packets of names which were out of order based on first name. I am assuming that is due to those names already being sorted prior to a shorter name later on. I tried to sort it multiple times in the code, and it gives me the same result. How are a and b picked out of the list?

Comment: This will only sort by the length of the names, not the names themselves. If you want to do that you need to compare the names directly where they are the same length.